# Delete : You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I am using following query to delete data which are not in another table.

```
delete from table_1 where tbl_id in  
(select tbl_id from table_1 left join table_2
on table_1.tbl_id=table_2.another_tbl_id where table_2.another_tbl_id is null)
```

Is there any issue in the above query?

It shows You can't specify target table 'table_1' for update in FROM clause.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: There are numerous **Related** questions with this exact same error. Are you telling us that none of them have the solution?

Comment: Yes. I checked all related questions. But not get cleared.

Comment: So you tried using an `INNER JOIN` like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause?rq=1 and it didn't work?

Comment: The [very first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause) related question I tried gave a full answer as to why your query does not work. You can't modify a table being used in a nested SELECT clause.

Comment: You can use below mention query to remove duplicate data from user table behalf of user_id -( DELETE n1 FROM user n1, user n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.user_id = n2.user_id);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easiest way is here ....

```
        DELETE t1 FROM table_1 t1 WHERE t1.tbl_id NOT IN  
         (SELECT another_tbl_id FROM  table_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
DELETE t1 FROM tablename1 t1 LEFT JOIN tablename2 tn2
ON t1.tbl_id=tn2.an`enter code here`other_tbl_id WHERE tn2.another_tbl_id IS NULL
```

Comment: What's the difference other than the added alias? It's still the same table.

Comment: I tried. not worked. adding alias shows syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `JOIN` rather than `IN`

```
DELETE table_1.* FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.tbl_id=table_2.another_tbl_id
WHERE table_2.another_tbl_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my Problem.

I modified the above query as follows:

```
delete from table_1 where tbl_id not in  
(select another_tbl_id from table_2)
```

Thanks for all your replies...

Comment: This is in the second answer in the duplicate question, which you said you already checked.